# Aligning Perfectly The X Axis Values of Density Plot and geom_col

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, alignment

I have a density plot and a col plot (`geom_col`), which I want to align perfectly according to the x axis's values.

The geom_col plot:

```
#creating the data 
col_plotting <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 20))
col_plotting[, 1] <- seq(0.1, 1, 0.1)
col_plotting[, 2] <- c(4.914910e-03, 2.485699e-17, 7.776309e-03, 1.177328e-01,
                       9.445104e-04, 7.739012e-02, 1.529308e-01, 4.829482e-01, 
                       2.902169e+00, 7.992388e+00)

#The figure
p.col_plotting <- ggplot(col_plotting, aes(x = V1, y = V2)) +
  geom_col() +
  xlab("Scores") +
  ylab("Incidence") +
  ggtitle(label="Proportion of Incidences For Each Score") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
        legend.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(seq(0.1, 1, 0.1)), 
                     minor_breaks = NULL, 
                     labels = c(seq(0.1, 1, 0.1)), 
                     limits = NULL, 
                     position = "bottom") #setting the x axis labels
```

The Density plot:

```
#the data
plotting <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = length(sample(seq(0, 1, 0.001)))))
plotting[, 1] <- sample(seq(0, 1, 0.001))
plotting[, 2] <- c(rep("Yes", 500), rep("No", nrow(plotting)-500))

#The plot
P.plotting <- ggplot(plotting, aes(V1, colour = V2, fill = V2))+
  xlab("Scores") +
  ggtitle(label = "Density plot for Desicions") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
        legend.title = element_text(face = "bold"))+
  geom_density(alpha = 0.60, size = 0.9) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cbPalette, name = "Desicion") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cbPalette, name = "Desicion")
```

Aligning them together while using cowplot

```
plot_grid(p.col_plotting, P.plotting, 
          labels = c("A", "B"), 
          nrow = 2, align = "v", axis = "lr")
```

Produces this figure :

[image]

The numbers are not perfectly aligned to each other.

I read  [this thread](https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/issues/14) that claims that the problem is with defining the x limits.

But the problem is that when I define the x limits of the `geom_col` to be from 0 to 1 (as it is in the data frame):

```
p.col_plotting <- ggplot(col_plotting, aes(x = V1, y = V2))+
  geom_col() +
  xlab("Scores") +
  ylab("Incidence") +
  ggtitle(label = "Proportion of Incidences For Each Score") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
        legend.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(seq(0.1, 1, 0.1)), 
                     minor_breaks = NULL, 
                     labels = c(seq(0.1, 1, 0.1)), 
                     limits = NULL, 
                     position = "bottom") +
  xlim(0, 1)
```

I get the warning:

> Warning message: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_col).

And the plot turns out like this:

[image]

I thought it would be best to just define the x limits for both the col plot and the density plot to be `(0, 1.1)`, but although the `geom_col` plot looks good, the density plot acquires a "tail" between the x axis values of 1 and 1.1, even though those values do not exist in the original plot data:

[image]

Also, the alignment is still not perfect, after I set the x limit values.

Next, I also tried two other solutions:

This code produced an error for trying to use `rbind` for 2 variable with un-equal dimensions

```
g2 <- ggplotGrob(p.col_plotting )
g3 <- ggplotGrob(P.plotting)
g <- rbind(g2, g3, size = "first")
g$widths <- grid::unit.pmax(g2$widths, g3$widths)
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(g)
```

This code produced the same un-aligned grid

```
g1 <- ggplotGrob(p.col_plotting)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(P.plotting)
colnames(g1) <- paste0(seq_len(ncol(g1)))
colnames(g2) <- paste0(seq_len(ncol(g2)))
x11()
grid::grid.draw(gridExtra::gtable_combine(g2, g1, along=2))
```

What else can I do?
Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if you could use [`ggExtra::ggMarginal`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggExtra/index.html) to produce this without having to mess with alignment? If you scroll half-way down the [`README.md`](https://github.com/daattali/ggExtra/blob/master/README.md), you'll see a nice look at `iris` with a layered density plot on each margin. (I haven't tested with your data, just a thought.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min, max))`. It sets limits without dropping data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

# Color-blind friendly colors
# (you forgot to add this variable)
cbPalette <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", 
               "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")


# Plot 1
p.col_plotting <- ggplot(col_plotting, aes(x = V1, y = V2)) +
    geom_col() +
    labs(title = "Proportion of Incidences for Each Score",
         x = "Scores", 
         y = "Incidence") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
          legend.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(seq(0, 1, 0.1))) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(seq(0, 1, 0.1)))

# Plot 2
p.plotting <- ggplot(plotting, aes(V1, colour = V2, fill = V2)) +
    labs(title = "Density Plot for Decisions", 
         x = "Scores",
         y = "Density") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
          legend.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
    geom_density(alpha = 0.60, size = 0.9) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = cbPalette, name = "Decision") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = cbPalette, name = "Decision")


# Plot Grid
plot_grid(p.col_plotting, p.plotting, labels = c("A", "B"), 
          nrow = 2, align = "v", axis = "lr")
```

[image: 1]

**edit**: I also took the liberty to clean up your code a little bit (simplify calls, remove typos).